# Turn.js more controls to make buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, turnjs

I've been looking on ways on how to make controls/button to manipulate turn.js to make my own magazine web page.

here is my html script

```
<div id="magazine">
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/01.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/02.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/03.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/04.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/05.jpg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(pages/06.jpg);"></div>
</div>

<a onclick="turntopage(4)">Go to page 4</a>
```

and i want to make some button controls like *Go to page 4*.
here is the javascript

```
//initialize turn js
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#magazine').turn({
        display: 'double',
        acceleration: true,
        gradients: !$.isTouch,
        elevation:50,
        when: {
            turned: function(e, page) {
                /*console.log('Current view: ', $(this).turn('view'));*/
            }
        }
    });
});
```

there is already way to do some next and previous controls

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==37)
        $('#magazine').turn('previous');
    else if (e.keyCode==39)
        $('#magazine').turn('next');
});
```

and i want to make controls for go to where ever page i want to go. is there a way i can do this?

Comment: `$("#magazine").turn("page", 4);` is your answer i guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is method for that

```
$("#magazine").turn("page",4)  // goto page number 4
```

http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/docs/18

Comment: i though i tried this one lately but let me see if that works. thanks

Comment: How about zooming controls. it cant make it work. sorry just new to jquery.

Comment: $("#magazine").turn("zoom", 0.5);   
Where 1 = 100% and 0.5 would scaled down to 50%;

Comment: wow thanks, where did you all this? i dont see it in documentation of turnjs.com. :(

Comment: $("#magazine").turn("zoom", 0.5); zoom turns out to be an invalid value. do you know why? is it my turn.js? if something is wrong with my turn.js where can i find one that have zoom function?