# Turn.js make an index for flipbook

Tags: javascript, turnjs

i am using turn.js (a script that makes a pape flipping effect) to publish my articles online, but i want to add an index with clickable links that jumps to a specific page

I've searched for my question here and the closest one is
[Turn.js more controls to make buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027185/turn-js-more-controls-to-make-buttons#comment17683508_13027185)

The answer was:
$("#magazine").turn("page",4)  // goto page number 4
Reference: http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/docs/18

Well i don't know where to put it and make it an action for a clickable link

sorry for the novice question i'm a graphics designer and a poet but i'm totally new to javascript coding

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know turn.js but you can try making a link which calls javascript as follows :

```
    <a href="javascript:$('#magazine').turn('page',4)">Index term</a>
```

Make your index a list of such links setting appropriate values for the page number and index term. A quick scan of the documentation showed no reason why this would not work.